# Question mark inside htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I should write an .htaccess rule to redirect:

```
www.foo.bar?page_id=125
```

to

```
www.bar.foo/anotherSubPage
```

This is my htaccess rule, that don't works. Where is my error?

```
RewriteRule ^?page_id=125(.*)$ http://www.bar.foo/anotherSubPage$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Some idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page_id=125(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.bar.foo/anotherSubPage? [R=301,L]
```

Because QUERY_STRING (after question mark) is not part of the left url in RewriteRule

Comment: Also, should he put `RewriteEngine On`? Been a while since I worked with .htaccess myself.

Comment: Croises, you rock! Thank You!